# Bison : Line number included in the error messages

Tags: c++, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

OK, so I suppose my question is quite self-explanatory.

I'm currently building a parser in Bison, and I want to make error reporting somewhat better.

Currently, I've set `%define parse.error verbose` (which actually gives messages like `syntax error, unexpected ***********************, expecting ********************`.

All I want is to add some more information in the error messages, e.g. line number (in input/file/etc)

My current `yyerror` (well nothing... unusual... lol) :

```
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\x1B[35mInterpreter : \x1B[37m%s\n",str);
}
```

---

**P.S.**

- I've gone through the [latest Bison documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html), but I seem quite lost...
- I've also had a look into the `%locations` directive, which most likely is *very* close to what I need - however, I still found no complete working example and I'm not sure how this is to be used.

Comment: Are you using flex to feed bison?

Comment: @Josh Yes. However, just to let you know, I've found a solution to the above issue based on a "combination" of answers on SO. And I'm currently adding it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, here I'm a with **a step-by-step solution** :

- We add the `%locations` directive in our grammar file (between `%}` and the first `%%`)
- We make sure that our lexer file contains an include for our parser (e.g. `#include "mygrammar.tab.h"`), at the top
- We add the `%option yylineno` option in our lexer file (between `%}` and the first `%%`)

And now, in our `yyerror` function (which will supposedly be in our lexer file), we may freely use this... `yylineno` *(= current line in file being processed)* :

```
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error | Line: %d\n%s\n",yylineno,str);
}
```

Yep. Simple as that! :-)

Comment: You really only need the 3rd bullet point to use `yylineno`, though the other two things may be useful for other reasons.

Comment: `%locations` (combined with `%option bison-locations` in the lexer file) gives you access to `yylloc`, which gives you both line and column information, but is a completely independent of `yylineno`.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `yylineo` is provided by `flex`. I.e. it needs external declaration if `yyerror` is implemented elsewhere. @Chris Dodd: `option bison-locations` sounds great but it did not work for me. If added it gives me an error at the first rule of the lexer: `yylval' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'`. I'm using bison `%union` fwiw... (flex 2.6.4/bison 3.0.4)

Comment: You also have to add `extern int yylineno;` in your bison file between `%}` and `%%`

Answer (score 3):

Whats worked for me was adding `extern int yylineno` in `.ypp` file:

```
/* parser.ypp */
%{
    extern int yylineno;
%}

/* scanner.lex */
...
%option yylineno
```

Answer (score 3):

Bison ships with a number of examples to demonstrate its features, see `/usr/local/share/doc/bison/examples` on your machine (where the prefix `/usr/local` depends on your configuration.

These examples in particular might be of interest to you:

- [lexcalc](https://github.com/akimd/bison/tree/master/examples/c/reccalc) uses precedence directives and location tracking.  It uses Flex to generate the scanner.
- [bistromathic](https://github.com/akimd/bison/tree/master/examples/c/bistromathic) demonstrates best practices when using Bison.

  - Its hand-written scanner tracks locations.
  - Its interface is pure.
  - It uses %params to pass user information to the parser and scanner.
  - Its scanner uses the `error` token to signal lexical errors and enter
    error recovery.
  - Its interface is "incremental", well suited for interaction: it uses the
    push-parser API to feed the parser with the incoming tokens.
  - It features an interactive command line with completion based on the
    parser state, based on `yyexpected_tokens`.
  - It uses Bison's standard catalog for internationalization of generated
    messages.
  - It uses a custom syntax error with location, lookahead correction and
    token internationalization.
  - Error messages quote the source with squiggles that underline the error:

  ```
  > 123 456
  1.5-7: syntax error: expected end of file or + or - or * or / or ^ before number
      1 | 123 456
        |     ^~~
  ```

  - It supports debug traces with semantic values.
  - It uses named references instead of the traditional $1, $2, etc.

Comment: @SeedyRom Well, I wouldn't know about Flex, but the documentation of Bison is carefully written, kept up to date, and meant to be readable and read.  Helpful criticism will be most welcome on bug-bison@gnu.org.

Comment: I should also mention that there are countless examples of calculators in "Flex/Bison" over the Internet, many of which are badly written, and/or are obsolete and not updated to newer idioms, and/or are actually more about Lex/Yacc.  The examples shipped with Bison should not have these defects.  If they do, a bug report should suffice to have them fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the examples for bison, this helped me figure out exactly what I was looking for. As well as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584201/490790 

And yeah the calculator examples are honestly just distracting because they're all awkward or older than sin.

Comment: One classical way to thank is to upvote the answer ;-)

Comment: Thought I liked this last night! I was in the zone with 100 tabs open lol. Thanks for the help again! I *hopefully* plan to make a tutorial on my findings and how to properly use flex/bison for reentrant push parsers (no C++). **I'll make sure to credit you.**