# How can I rewrite the programs, so that I don't have to call `flex` but only call `bison` and `cc`?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, bison, flex-lexer

I already have a calculator program based on bison and flex which takes input from command line arguments.

Now how can I rewrite the programs, so that I don't have to call `flex` but only call `bison` and `cc` during building process? (Achieve something similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499190/where-is-the-official-documentation-debian-package-iproute-doc#comment919875_499225).

```
$ ./fb1-5 '1+3'
= 4
```

Makefile:

```
fb1-5:  fb1-5.l fb1-5.y
    bison -d fb1-5.y
    flex fb1-5.l
    cc -o $@ fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
```

fb1-5.y

```
/* simplest version of calculator */

%{
#  include <stdio.h>
%}

/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token OP CP

%%

calclist: /* nothing */
 | calclist exp { printf("= %d\n> ", $2); }
 ;

exp: factor
 | exp ADD exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 | exp ABS factor { $$ = $1 | $3; }
 ;

factor: term
 | factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 | factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 ;

term: NUMBER
 | ABS term { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
 | OP exp CP { $$ = $2; }
 ;
%%
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // printf("> ");
  if(argc > 1) {
    if(argv[1]){
      yy_scan_string(argv[1]);
    }
  }

  yyparse();
  return 0;
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

fb1-5.l:

```
/* recognize tokens for the calculator and print them out */

%{
# include "fb1-5.tab.h"
%}

%%
"+" { return ADD; }
"-" { return SUB; }
"*" { return MUL; }
"/" { return DIV; }
"|"     { return ABS; }
"("     { return OP; }
")"     { return CP; }
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }

"//".*  
[ \t]   { /* ignore white space */ }
.   { yyerror("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

---

**Update:**

I tried to follow the advice in the reply, see the modified code below. in `main()`, why is `yyerror()` called before `printf("argv[%d]: %s ", n, argv[n])`? Isn't `yyerror()` called only by `yyparse()`, and isn't `yyparse` only called after `printf("argv[%d]: %s ", n, argv[n])` in `main()` in `main()`.

```
$ ./fb1-5  2*4
2*4error: �
= 8
```

`fb1-5.y`:

```
/* simplest version of calculator */

%{
#  include <stdio.h>
  FILE * fin;
  int yylex (void);
  void yyerror(char *s);  
  %}

/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token OP CP

%%

calclist: /* nothing */
 | calclist exp { printf("= %d\n", $2); }
 ;

exp: factor
 | exp ADD exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 | exp ABS factor { $$ = $1 | $3; }
 ;

factor: term
 | factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 | factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 ;

term: NUMBER
 | ABS term { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
 | OP exp CP { $$ = $2; }
 ;
%%




/* The lexical analyzer returns a double floating point
   number on the stack and the token NUM, or the numeric code
   of the character read if not a number.  It skips all blanks
   and tabs, and returns 0 for end-of-input.  */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int yylex (void)
{
  char c;

/* Skip white space.  */
  while ((c = getc(fin)) == ' ' || c == '\t'){
    continue;
  }

  // printf("%s", &c);

  /* Process numbers.  */
  if (c == '.' || isdigit (c))
    {
      ungetc(c, fin);
      fscanf (fin, "%d", &yylval);
      return NUMBER;
    }

  /* Process addition.  */
  if (c == '+')
    {
      return ADD;
    }

  /* Process sub.  */
  if (c == '-')
    {
      return SUB;
    }

  /* Process mult.  */
  if (c == '*')
    {
      return MUL;
    }

  /* Process division.  */
  if (c == '/')
    {
      return DIV;
    }

  /* Process absolute.  */
  if (c == '|')
    {
      return ABS;
    }

   /* Process left paren.  */
   if (c == '(')
    {
      return OP;
    }

  /* Process right paren.  */
  if (c == ')')
    {
      return CP;
    }

  /* Return a single char.  */
  yyerror(&c);
  return c;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // evaluate each command line arg as an arithmetic expression
  int n=1;
  while (n < argc) {
    if(argv[n]){
      // yy_scan_string(argv[n]);
      // fin = stdin;
      fin = fmemopen(argv[n], strlen (argv[n]), "r");
      printf("%s ",argv[n]);
      fflush(stdout);
      yyparse();
    }
    n++;
  }

  return 0;
}

void yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: `flex` reads the input. `bison` doesn't: it just calls `flex`. You don't have to do anything to `bison` to take the input from the command line. The grammar has nothing do with it either. Removing `flex` doesn't accomplish your objective. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: If what you really want is to read from a string (like a command line arg) instead of a file, you can just use flex's `yy_scan_string` function to read from a string instead of a file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic implementation of a lexical scanner in the [examples section of the bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Rpcalc-Lexer). (Slightly less basic versions are later in the manual.)

That won't help you directly because it is based on `fscanf`, which means that it works on an input stream. Most C libraries contain functions which let you treat a character string as a `FILE*` (see, for example, the Posix standard [fmemopen](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html)). Failing that, you'd have to replace the getc and scanf calls with string based alternatives, which means you will need to keep track of a buffer and input pointer somewhere. `strtoul` (or `strtod`) will prove useful because the second argument helps you keep track of how much of the string was used by the number.

Comment: Thanks. could you show me the code after change? I am still reading bison's manual.

Comment: @tim: i think you would learn a lot more if you at least try to write the code yourself. It's really not that complicated.

Comment: Thanks. See my update. I can't figure out how bison uses yyflex() and my modification doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you doing all those `ungetc` calls? You don't unget a token you have handled... Bison calls yylex when it needs a token. Yylex returns a token. That's it. It's not more complicated than that.

Comment: Also, using single character tokens as with the example in the bison manual does make everything simpler. But you can do it your way, too.

Comment: I am stuck because I can't figure out how bison uses yyflex().  I just want to see how  the program  can be converted to not use flex, to help me understand that

Comment: @tim: what do you not understand about "bison calls `yylex()` when it needs a token. `yylex()` returns a token."?

Comment: after removing all ungetc calls, it still doesn't work. There are more problems than you mentioned. Could you just show the correct conversion to not using flex?

Comment: @tim: you need the ungetc before the scanf. Do you see why? That should be sufficient to make it work.

Comment: Looking at it more closely, it would be good to add `if (c == EOF) return 0;` but I think it will work without that. Read the "debugging your parser" section of the bison manual to see how to enable bison's trace facility, which might help you debug your parser.

Comment: Thanks. See my update. when is `yyerror()`  called? Why is it called before `printf("argv[%d]: %s ", n, argv[n])` in `main()`?

Comment: @tim: it isn't. Your printf in main doesn't output a newline so its output is buffered. The fprintf to stderr happens immediately because stderr is unbuffered. There are lots of SO posts about this aspect of the C library (nothing to do with bison or flex).

Comment: Thanks. updated my code. (1) What  and why is that mysterious character in `error: �` in the output?  (2) How shall I place the call to `yyerror()`? I want it to be called only if a character is not recognized. But it is called  out of my expectation

Comment: @tim: (updated comment). See my comment about handling `EOF`. Since you don't handle it, the `EOF` triggers a call to `yyerror`. Note that the argument to `yyerror` is supposed to be a NUL-terminated character array, and that a single `char` is not NUL-terminated. That results in Undefined Behaviour, which might result in a segfault, printing garbage (as you see), or any other random outcome. This has nothing to do with bison or flex either. Also: `c` should be an `int`, not a`char`; `getc` returns an `int` because `EOF` isn't a valid `char`. See `man getc`.