# How can I output the exact location of an error in my Bison code?

Tags: c, bison

how to output the exact location of the error when I input a error command
here is my bison code of command

```
command:
    SAVE STRING opt_depth opt_exclude{ printf("Command parsed successfully.\n"); }
    | error { printf("Error: Invalid command.\n"); }
    ;
```

for example,input is "save x1 depth=1 exclude=[w1",then it will tell me that there is an error in exclude(lacks ']')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bison : Line number included in the error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407730/bison-line-number-included-in-the-error-messages)